# Is it possible to use tbl_regression function with coxme function with random effect?

Tags: r, random, model, cox-regression

do you know if there is a way to get a publication ready table for a random model generated with `coxme`? I tried this code but I assume it works only with `lme`?

```
coxme(Surv(followup, dod) ~ responder + (1|center) + stage, data = d) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE, tidy_fun = broom.mixed::tidy)
```

thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For the fixed effects of a coxme model try:

```
tidy_fun = broom.helpers::tidy_parameters
```